# Can't start rabbitmq interface

Tags: rabbitmq

I have RabbitMQ installed and started. The service is running. However, after I launched this URL : http://localhost:15672 to open the management interface in Chrome, I occured this error:

```
This site is unreachable localhost took too long to respond.
Here are a few tips :

Check connection
Check proxy and firewall
Run Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

When i want to check the port is in use, i found the rabbitmq ports:

```
[root@VM-STANDARD ~]# sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
beam.smp  16482 rabbitmq   80u  IPv4 3706947      0t0  TCP *:25672 (LISTEN)
beam.smp  16482 rabbitmq   93u  IPv4 3707021      0t0  TCP *:15672 (LISTEN)
beam.smp  16482 rabbitmq   94u  IPv6 3707042      0t0  TCP *:5672 (LISTEN)
```

Node : rabbit@VM-STANDARD: RabbitMQ 3.8.14 on Erlang 23.2.7

Any ideas please, thanks.

Comment: try to use the `VM-STANDARD` ip instead of localhost. `http://<<VM-STANDARDIP>>:15672 `

Comment: @GabrieleSantomaggio : The same problem suddenly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can try :

> ```
> > rabbitmqctl add_user admin admin 
> > systemctl stop rabbitmq-server systemctl start rabbitmq-server
> > rabbitmqctl set_user_tags admin administrator   
> > rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / admin “.*“ “.*“ “.*“
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried - http://hostname:15672

Sometimes localhost will not work.

Comment: the same thing, not working , it display-->This site is unreachable Check if the hostname address is correct.
If there is no error, try to do a Windows network diagnostic.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN